# Open Graph Warnings that should be fixed - Extraneous Property- How to fix?

Tags: facebook-opengraph

We implemented open graph tags in our website few times back. I checked it in FB debugger tool and find the Og property errors. Check it [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.lenskart.com/tag-heuer-club-7508-dark-red-grey-outdoor-106-sunglasses.html).

Please suggest how to fix the OG properties issue.

Comment: Just remove the `Extraneous Property`

Comment: Thanks Shivan for your kind response. but can't we correct it rather removing extraneous property. Is this the issue with code or these are optional properties which we shouldn't use?

Please help me out..

Comment: which documentation did you follow to add these properties?

Comment: We took help from here- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/product/

Comment: Could you please help and share how to resolve this. I'm new to this and want to understand whole process..

Comment: seems you have `og:type` that does not support these properties. See the question I marked duplicate